# Why does my embedded chart cause Excel to crash if I don't open VBA first?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts, vba7

I have an embedded chart on a protected Excel sheet that I would like to process chart events on (MouseMove and MouseDown), but Excel crashes when I click on the chart *unless* I first open the VBA editor. If I don't open VBA and click on the chart, Excel crashes. If I open VBA and click on the chart, the mouse events work as expected.

I would like to be able to open the workbook and see chart events work without having to open and close the VBA editor first.

I was able to replicate the problem in a new workbook:

I created a new workbook and added new empty line chart with the name `MyChart`.

In VBA, I created a new class module named `clsChartEvents` with the following contents:

```vb
Public WithEvents ChartClass As Chart

Private Sub ChartClass_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Value = Button
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3").Value = Shift
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value = x & ", " & y
End Sub

Private Sub ChartClass_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value = Button
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value = Shift
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G2").Value = x & ", " & y
End Sub
```

And I added the following to the `ThisWorkbook` VBA module:

```vb
Dim modChartEvents As New clsChartEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Set chtObj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("MyChart")
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect
    
    chtObj.Locked = False
    chtObj.Chart.ProtectSelection = True
    chtObj.ProtectChartObject = True
    Set modChartEvents.ChartClass = chtObj.Chart
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

After saving, closing, and reopening the workbook, I'm expecting to see the button, shift, and x,y info displayed in Sheet1 when I click on the chart and move my mouse around. Instead, Excel crashes. However, it does work as expected if I open VBA editor first (either leaving it open or immediately closing it).

**Update 4/12**: I moved the code I had in `Workbook_Open` to a new Public Sub named `InitChartEvents` and put the inverse of it in `Workbook_Open`, to "revert" the chart attributes on Open:

```vb
chtObj.Locked = True
chtObj.Chart.ProtectSelection = False
chtObj.ProtectChartObject = False
Set modChartEvents.ChartClass = Nothing
```

After saving and reopening the workbook, Excel does not crash when I click on the chart (because its attributes are reverted to defaults on open). A few different things I tested:

- If I run `InitChartEvents` by clicking a button, Excel will crash when I click the chart.
- If I run `InitChartEvents` from a function like `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`, Excel will crash when I click the chart.
- If I run `InitChartEvents` from Developer tab > Macros, then Excel does *not* crash and chart events *work as expected*.

The button and selection change event were tests to see if the chart or chart object weren't being initialized/loaded until after the Workbook_Open ran. These let me trigger the same code by an action I could take after fully opening the workbook.

I'm puzzled and left wondering what is special about opening VBA or using the Macros window to run the code.

Comment: Having the VBProject Window open makes the application analyze any active Watched values/expressions. One time, I was plagued with a bug that seemingly came out of nowhere. Turns out, one of my watched expressions was running a function that was altering the variables instead of just reading the values. By having the code window open, the macro was running differently and having bugs that didnt exist when I closed the window. You might have the opposite. Do you have any watched expressions?